# Yii get project root

Tags: php, yii, yii1.x

For example I have Yii project in location `/var/www/yii`. How to get this path from controller?

What I try `Yii::app()->basePath;` I get `/var/www/yii/module-name`.

I need only `/var/www/yii`. Of course I can modify this URL with `str_replace()`, but maybe there is a way to get clearly this root?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it like below:

```
echo Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot');
```

This will return the result you want:

```
var/www/yii/
```

If you want to get your application path, you can:

```
echo Yii::getPathOfAlias('application');
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it an option to get the parent directory of the given path using `dirname`?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php

Answer (score 0):

```
echo Yii::app()->getBasePath();
```